# Filtering items with dropdown in react

Tags: reactjs

So,I am creating a bookstore app.In that user can search and filter the books.The filtering of books works for one time and next it goes empty.I know where i was doing wrong.After filtering I was setting the state to the filtered state.How to correct it???

Here is the code....

```
    class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          books: [],
          userInput: "",
        };
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
          books: BOOK_DATA,
        });
      }
      handleInputChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
          userInput: event.target.value,
        });
      };
      handleCategoryChange = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.value.toLowerCase());
        const books = [...this.state.books];
    
        const categorizedBooks = books.filter((book) => {
          return book.category === event.target.value.toLowerCase();
        });
        //Problem here
        this.setState({
          books: categorizedBooks,
        });
      };
      render() {
        const { books, userInput } = this.state;
        //This one is for searching books
        const searchedBook = books.filter((book) => {
          return book.name.toLowerCase().includes(userInput);
        });
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <Header />
            <SearchBox change={(event) => this.handleInputChange(event)} />
            <CategoriesandFilter
              handleCategoryChange={(event) => this.handleCategoryChange(event)}
            />
            <ShopTitle />
            <BooksComponent books={searchedBook} />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: If you know what you have done wrong, why do you still need help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the already filtered data for the next filter. you need to use the unfiltered data.

```
...
const categorizedBooks = BOOK_DATA.filter((book) => { // Use your unfiltered data here (BOOK_DATA)
  return book.category === event.target.value.toLowerCase();
});
...
```

Comment: Thanks man.I am a beginner in the react.I thought copying the books array to another variable would be enough.By the way,it works now.